# Is there a way to load HTML/JS files with Vapor in a local iOS Webserver?

Tags: swift, xcode, webserver, vapor

I have created a simple game in JS and now I am trying to implement it in an iOS app. The best way I could think of doing that is by running a local Webserver in the iOS App using Vapor. But I don't really know how to load my existing HTML/JS files.

Comment: How would this work? How would you access the local webserver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [FileMiddleware](https://docs.vapor.codes/advanced/middleware/#file-middleware) to serve static assets from a Vapor server, including existing JS and HTML files